# How to hide or show a div based on its contents

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hi I'm trying to hide/show a `div` based on an AJAX response. I really don't know, is there way for that?

If response is an error, show the error text and show the div (same div).

If response is not an error, show the success text and hide a div (same div).

It's like facebook function.

I should do that with javascript function(s).

**EDIT**
Added information from OP's duplicate question:

There are my divs.

```
<div id="messages"></div>
<div id="edit-address-book">
codes to edit the address book , input type - text, select , textearea etc...
</div>
```

Down below there is one of my simple ajax requests. 
This is the ajax library , that I use -> http://en.dklab.ru/lib/JsHttpRequest/

```
 // Create new JsHttpRequest object.
 var req_update = new JsHttpRequest();
 // Code automatically called on load finishing.
 req_update.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (req_update.readyState == 4) {
  document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = req_update.responseJS.messages;
  document.getElementById("changed_address").value = req_update.responseJS.changed_address;
  }
 }

 document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = req_update.responseJS.messages;

 req_update.responseJS.messages; // This is ajax respond part.
```

On the address book div, when customer click on update button there comes error or success message from ajax respond into messages div.

For Example:

```
    Error Messages:
    -----------------
    Your First Name must contain a minimum of 2 characters.
    Your Last Name must contain a minimum of 2 characters.
    Your Street Address must contain a minimum of 5 characters.
    Your City must contain a minimum of 3 characters.
    Your State must contain a minimum of 2 characters.

    Success Message:
    --------------------
    Your address book has been successfully updated. (
```

I've tried it simply down below, but it didn't work:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
if ( document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML == "<?php echo SUCCESS_MESSAGE; ?>" ) {
 hide_div('edit-address-book); //The div to hide the address book entries.
}
</script>
```

if there is a suggest/solution in jquery javascript library, I can use it as well.

Comment: Please provide more context; do you want to achieve this in jQuery, straight JS, etc. Also show any code you're working on.

Comment: sure you can do that. you need to detect/parse the error with your own logic though unless you use a framework like jQuery, Prototype, Dojo, etc..

Comment: What do you mean by "error?" Do you mean a transport or connection error, or perhaps an error that is generated by your logic on the server (i.e.: a database error that is being reported back to the client)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally I've found the solution. It will help users, who are using the AJAX library "JSHttpRequest" ( http://en.dklab.ru/lib/JsHttpRequest/ ).
Here it is:**

#### Find:

```
    document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = req_update.responseJS.messages;
    document.getElementById("changed_address").value = req_update.responseJS.changed_address;
```

**###Replace with:**

```
    document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = req_update.responseJS.messages;

    if (req_update.responseJS.messages == "<?php echo SUCCESS_MESSAGE; ?>") {
        hide_div("edit-address-book");
    }

    document.getElementById("changed_address").value = req_update.responseJS.changed_address;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do it.

**EDITED**

```
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function teste(divId, text){
        var myDiv = document.getElementById(divId);

        if (myDiv.innerText.indexOf(text, 0) != -1) //could be replaced by any error veryfing logic
        {
            myDiv.style.visibility = "hidden";
            return 'Message 1';
        }
        else
        {
            myDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
            return 'Message 2';
        }
    }

</script>


<div id="MyDiv">blabla</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(teste('MyDiv', 'blabla'));
</script>



</body>
```

Comment: This only meets half of the requirements. It needs to be able to show the div as well.

Comment: At least I gave a starter, and you gave me -1? do you really think the answer is not useful? Why don't you post something useful instead of just whining?